# Genetic algorithm, is elitism necessary if crossover is low?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I wondering about the crossover stage in GA's. From what ive understood, 0.7 => 70% chance of crossover occurring, is a typical value to begin with. If your parents selection process is based on the returned fitness of a specific chromosome, then there's a high probability of the fittest chromosome getting through anyway and not experiencing crossover, so is elitism really necessary?

Im i also need to apply a filter to remove duplicate chromosomes from each generation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even with a high crossover rate, and a selection process which selects higher chromosome to crossover there is always a chance (no matter how small) that you will lose the best chromosome from one generation to the next. Elitism means that once a good result is found, it will always remain in the population until a better result is found.

No matter how small the chance of losing your best result, it is always a good idea to employ a safe guard to ensure that it won't ever happen.

In regards to removing duplicate chromosome, it isn't necessary but it can often ensure that the population doesn't become stale and populated with the same chromosome. Generally I apply a function which does not remove duplicate chromosome every generation but after a given number of generations. This is largely to improve the overall speed of the algorithm but can be implemented every generation if required.

Removing duplicates also becomes less necessary with a higher mutation rate, since mutation in itself stops the population from being filled with all the same chromosome. Personally, I prefer to apply both duplicate removal and mutation although they effectively perform the same task. In my experience though with genetic algorithms variety is always good so having different functions for the same task can often produce better results.

Comment: You don't need Elitism to remember the best-so-far solution. You could just have a variable that stores this information and that is not used for mating. Elitism is useful if there is a strong correlation between fitness and distance to the optimum in the solution space.

Comment: Elitism isn't necessary, but then if you're storing the best solution found so far and not ensuring that it's carried forward for mating then there's less chance of it improving. The point of genetic algorithms is to constantly improve a solution. Not using your best solution so far seems counter productive.

Comment: In a very dynamic environment where the best solution is changing all the time, elitism would decrease the convergence. It strongly depends on the use case if it improves the GA or not. The usage of elitism is just one of many parameters of the algorithmn and you need to test which parameters work good for your use case.

Comment: Indeed. I guess my answer was slightly biased based on my own work with GA's, where elitism has almost always improved convergence. Apologies if I came across as saying elitism is necessary. As with most GA operators, it can be highly situational.

Comment: "In my experience though with genetic algorithms variety is always good so having different functions for the same task can often produce better results." are u referring to genetic programming here, ie having several methods which do the a similar task but differently and then getting the GA to identify which is best?